# Nominal voltage ratings in Brazil?

Tags: electrical-engineering

What are the nominal voltage ratings and operating tolerances for 60-Hz electric power systems above 100 volts up to a maximum system voltage of 1 kV in Brazil?
I am looking for a document like ANSI C84, that describes typical distribution service and equipment nameplate voltage ranges and tolerances.

I know about 60% of the population is served by a 127 Volt system and a minority is served by a 220V system and both systems use the same type N plug.

For example is the 127 Volt system split phase 127/256 like North American 120/240?
Is the 220 Volt system split phase 220/440 ?
What are the standard three phase voltages, 220Y127, 380Y220 ?
Thank you

Comment: A quick google gives https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/brazil/ so they don't follow America... wonder why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Brazil, the most common (domestic distribution) system is a three phase 4 wire one, with the most common voltages being 127/220 and 220/380 (with many exceptions).
On 127/220, some houses will have a connection to two phases and the neutral, giving the choice to use either voltages.
On 220/380, most houses will probably work with only one phase, as pretty much all domestic products works at either 127 or 220, while 380 is used mostly on industry.

Not completely sure about the next info, but it seems that 110/220 used to be a thing in the past, probably with a split phase like in the US, but sometime at around 1999 there was a resolution that made it change to the actual system. The funny point is that the usual voltages are called "110 and 220" up to this day, even when the "110V" is actually 127V and most Brazilians don't even know it.

Information on that is decently hard to find even in the native language (PT-BR), but some decent overall info can be found [here](https://www.mundodaeletrica.com.br/diferentes-niveis-de-tensao-quais-sao/#:%7E:text=Onde%20tem%20tens%C3%A3o%20el%C3%A9trica%20de,voc%C3%AA%20tem%20os%20380%20Volts.), and a list with the three phase voltages by State can be found [here](https://www.portalsolar.com.br/tabela-de-trifasico-no-brasil-220v-e-380v).